# Qml application strange behavior on nvidia card enabled

Tags: linux, qt, qml, nvidia

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with two graphics card - first from Intel and the second one is NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M]. On Intel card every qml applications works well, but on nvidia card, [even the simplest qml](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-tutorial1.html), not. When I am resizing window, the window content "flows" faster than window is resizing and disappears outside window frame leaving artifacts. [Just watch this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pG2SfQ1F62s) To enable nvidia card I am using optirun from bumblebee package. Please help me to solve this problem.

edit: On NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520M] is the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed bumblebee and installed nvidia-prime (remember to set nvidia in nvidia-setting and remove bumblebee nvidia blacklists). Problem gone, so the problem is with the bumblebee.